# What is the Hiraishin no Jutsu's weakness?

Tags: naruto

Itachi has mentioned in his fight with Kabuto that every jutsu has a weakness, I'm curious as to know what the teleportation jutsu's weaknesses are. Minato seemed to be able to spam the jutsu constantly with no perceivable side-effects.

A possible weakness could be that the user can only teleport to something that has been marked, but there has been no indication that there are any limits to the amount of jutsu formulas Minato could make and also when something has been marked it stays marked forever.

The only real perceived weakness is that it is a jutsu that takes a Hokage level shinobi to master, it does seem to have one hell of a learning curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Over-reliance** and **Predictability**

If the opponent knows that *Hiraishin no Jutsu* allows the user to teleport to marked *kunai* and area, it would be "easily" countered.

- Minato vs Raikage: if Raikage also knew that Minato left his mark on Bee, he (Raikage) could instantly move to Bee (at this point Raikage already spotted almost all of Minato's *kunai*) and Minato would probably moved to other kunai and Raikage would chase him again (I don't know what the final outcome would be, though)
- Tobirama vs Madara: Madara immediately countered Tobirama the moment he used *Hiraishingiri* because Madara had seen that move before

Of course this can happen (*Hiraishin* being countered) only if the user of this *jutsu* rely on it too much and can't finish his/her opponent immediately.

Edit: oh and also if the opponent is fast physically or reactively

Edit 2: Madara sensed Tobirama with Sage Mode, then he's fast enough to dodge it.